# ILMerge のコマンドが通らない原因が知りたい

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

提示コードですがILMerge.exeのコマンドが通らない原因が知りたいです。
`オブジェクト参照がオブジェクト インスタンスに設定されていません。`とはどいう意味なのでしょうか？参考サイトを参考にコマンドを入力したのですが以下のエラーが表示され`.dll`を`.exe`に含めることが出来ません。

###### 試したこと

以下のようにA,Bのコマンドを試しました。
`LIMerge.exe　オプション　含めたいexe dllファイル` 
のように色々試しました。

参考サイト：
https://qiita.com/mkit0031/items/5edde5926217a11aca85
https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/fdotnet/dotnettips/426ilmerge/ilmerge.html

###### 実行したコマンドA

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /ndebug /targetplatform:v4 /ndebug /wildcards /out:piyo.exe C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\HEIC_SimpleConverter\HEIC_SimpleConverter\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\HEIC_SimpleConverter.exe *.dll
```

###### コマンドプロンプトA

```
C:\Users\xxx>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /ndebug /targetplatform:v4 /ndebug /wildcards /out:piyo.exe C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\HEIC_SimpleConverter\HEIC_SimpleConverter\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\HEIC_SimpleConverter.exe *.dll
An exception occurred during merging:
オブジェクト参照がオブジェクト インスタンスに設定されていません。
   場所 System.Compiler.CoreSystemTypes.GetSystemAssembly(Boolean doNotLockFile, Boolean getDebugInfo)
   場所 System.Compiler.CoreSystemTypes.Initialize(Boolean doNotLockFile, Boolean getDebugInfo)
   場所 System.Compiler.SystemTypes.Initialize(Boolean doNotLockFile, Boolean getDebugInfo)
   場所 ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   場所 ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

###### 実行したコマンドB

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /ndebug /targetplatform:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5" /ndebug /wildcards /out:piyo.exe C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\HEIC_SimpleConverter\HEIC_SimpleConverter\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\HEIC_SimpleConverter.exe *.dll
```

###### コマンドプロンプトB

```
C:\Users\xxxx>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /ndebug /targetplatform:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5" /ndebug /wildcards /out:piyo.exe C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\HEIC_SimpleConverter\HEIC_SimpleConverter\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\HEIC_SimpleConverter.exe *.dll
An exception occurred during merging:
Platform 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5' not recognized.
   場所 ILMerging.ILMerge.SetTargetPlatform(String platform, String dir)
   場所 ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   場所 ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ILMergeは.NET Frameworkを対象としていますが、質問のコードは.NET 6.0のようですので対象外です。

それとは別に、別スレッドでの質問を見る限り、ImageMagickを使用されていると思いますが、こちらにネイティブコードが含まれているため、どの道マージすることができません。拡張子が`.DLL`であっても、ILMerge等が対象とするのは.NET Assemblyですが、ImageMagickなどが使用するネイティブDLLは対象外となります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問ですが配布するアプリをWindows formで作ったのですがその場合.exeと.jsonファイル等も全部含めるのでしょうか？

Comment: @samidare_chan 一問一答形式です。`ILMerge`と関係ない話題のようなので、本スレッドを解決済みとして別質問を立ててください。